# How to insert text before the first line of a file on Mac OS

Tags: bash, macos, sed

Trying to write a bash script that adds a new line in each text-file of a given folder, I tried `sed`. I have a working code that adds the text "blablabla" at line 1

But how:

- do I add a carriage return after this "blablabla"-text ?
- do it for all files(`.txtaa/.txtab/.txtac`) in a given folder ?

Here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

sed '1i\
blablabla' miFile.txt > myNewFile.txt
```

Comment: Where do you want to add the carriage return? last line of each file?

Comment: No - I want to add it right after my "blablabla"-text (so that this text gets inserted as the first line of all the text-files in the folder)

Comment: So you want to insert some text e.g. `blabla` as the first line of a file followed by the rest of the lines?

Comment: exactly ! this is what I would like...

Comment: What's wrong with just `{ echo 'blablabla'; cat miFile.txt; } > myNewFile.txt`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the ever POSIX compliant line oriented text editor [`ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html#tag_20_40) for quick in place edit on files.

This should work on Mac OS or any POSIX compliant shells available out there. In your script, assuming you want to do that for every file in a folder just execute the script below.

You must be *inside* the folder of your wish before running the script. For e.g. `cd myFolder/` and run it:

Since you have multiple file extensions as you claim, you can use a glob pattern as `*.txt*`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob
for file in *.txt*; do 
    ex -sc '1i|blablabla' -cx "$file"
done
```

Or if you are running from a parent folder you could modify the loop construct to have

```
for file in myFolder/*.txt*; do
```

As mentioned in the linked page, the `1` selects the first line of the file, `i|<text>` inserts the `<text>` of your choice followed by a newline character, and `x` closes the file.

Remember this operation is done *in-place* meaning you cannot recover back the file being modified. Make sure you are *absolutely* sure of the replacement text to be done or) have a backup of the folder once before doing this operation.

Comment: I wasn't quite correct - I split the files and therefore I have the endings .txtaa / .txtab / .txtac / etc etc - Therefore the newest solution does not work here. But I added `*.txt*` to the script - And now everything works brilliant !!! Thank you very much for your support !!!